# Socket.Receive() stop receiving and window size decrease to zero

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a tcp connection and two threads to handle sending and receiving respectively. Sometimes the receiving thread can not receive any data after a few minutes the program started,then get a Timeout error from the Receive() method. But Wireshark shows me there is data on the wire and because the program stop receiving, the receiving window size decrease to zero.

Seems like this happens more frequently on my laptop which is a windows 7 running by Parallels on  Mac OS X.

```
class Test
{
    public static string Host { get; set; }
    public static int Port { get; set; }
    public static Action<Exception> ErrorHandler { get; set; }

    private Socket socket;
    private object sendSync;

    private Thread recvThread;
    private Thread sendThread;
    private Thread connectThread;

    private readonly int RECEIVETIMOUT = 20 * 1000;
    private readonly int MAXCONNECTATTEMPTINTERVAL = 27;

    private int connectingAttempt = 0;

    private ManualResetEvent sendReadyEvent;
    private ManualResetEvent receiveReadyEvent;
    private ManualResetEvent sendStoppedEvent;
    private ManualResetEvent receiveStoppedEvent;


    private Queue<byte[]> waitingRequests;

    private Test()
    {
        sendSync = new object();
        waitingRequests = new Queue<byte[]>();

        sendReadyEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        receiveReadyEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        sendStoppedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);
        receiveStoppedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);

        sendThread = new Thread(this.Send);
        sendThread.IsBackground = true;
        sendThread.Start();

        recvThread = new Thread(this.Receive);
        recvThread.IsBackground = true;
        recvThread.Start();

        connectThread = new Thread(this.Connect);
        connectThread.IsBackground = true;
        connectThread.Start();

        callbackThread = new Thread(this.callback);
        callbackThread.IsBackground = true;
        callbackThread.Start();
    }

    private static Test instance = null;
    public static Test GetInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new Test();
        return instance;
    }

    private void Connect()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                sendStoppedEvent.WaitOne();
                receiveStoppedEvent.WaitOne();

                socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                socket.ReceiveTimeout = RECEIVETIMOUT;

                var ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Host)[0];
                var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, Port);
                socket.Connect(endPoint);

                sendStoppedEvent.Reset();
                receiveStoppedEvent.Reset();

                startSend();
                startReceive();
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                var waitSecond = (int)Math.Pow(3, connectingAttempt);
                if (waitSecond >= MAXCONNECTATTEMPTINTERVAL)
                {
                    waitSecond = MAXCONNECTATTEMPTINTERVAL;
                    if(ErrorHandler !=null)
                        ErrorHandler(e);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(waitSecond * 1000);
                connectingAttempt++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Send(byte[] request)
    {
        lock (sendSync)
        {
            waitingRequests.Enqueue(request);
            Monitor.Pulse(sendSync);
        }
    }

    private void Send()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            sendReadyEvent.WaitOne();
            byte[] bytes;
            lock (sendSync)
            {
                if (waitingRequests.Count == 0)
                    Monitor.Wait(sendSync)
                bytes = waitingRequests.Dequeue();
            }

            int i = 0;
            while (i < bytes.Length)
            {
                try
                {
                    i += socket.Send(bytes, i, bytes.Length - i, SocketFlags.None);
                }
                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    stopSend();
                    break;
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
                {
                    stopSend();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopSend()
    {
        socket.Close();
        sendReadyEvent.Reset();
        sendStoppedEvent.Set();
    }

    private void startSend()
    {
        sendReadyEvent.Set();
    }

    private int totalReceived = 0;
    private int  recevied = 0;

    private void Receive()
    {
        int RECVBUFFERSIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 2;
        byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[RECVBUFFERSIZE];
        while (true)
        {
            receiveReadyEvent.WaitOne();
            try
            {
                recevied = socket.Receive(recvBuffer, totalReceived, 1024, SocketFlags.None);
                if (recevied == 0)
                    stopReceive();
                totalReceived += recevied;
                //parse data
                ......
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                stopReceive();
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
            {
                stopReceive();
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopReceive()
    {
        totalReceived = 0;
        recevied = 0;

        socket.Close();
        receiveReadyEvent.Reset();
        receiveStoppedEvent.Set();
    }

    private void startReceive()
    {
        receiveReadyEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

Here is the Wireshark dump

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info

4850 1971.053146 client        server        TCP      90     netview-aix-3 > autodesk-nlm [PSH, ACK] Seq=7969 Ack=188674 Win=232 Len=36

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info

4851 1971.077669 server        client        TCP      286    [TCP Window Full] autodesk-nlm > netview-aix-3 [PSH, ACK] Seq=188674 Ack=7969 Win=28544 Len=232

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info

4852 1971.077672 server        client        TCP      60     autodesk-nlm > netview-aix-3 [ACK] Seq=188906 Ack=8005 Win=28544 Len=0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info

4853 1971.077766 client        server        TCP      189    [TCP ZeroWindow] netview-aix-3 > autodesk-nlm [PSH, ACK] Seq=8005 Ack=188906 Win=0 Len=135

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I expect you're going to have to post code.  If the local port is advertising a receive window size of zero then the local TCP stack has accepted as much data as it can and the application is not reading it.